# Expo will not run the app Error: could not connect to TCP port 5554: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5554:

Tags: react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code, expo

I am using windows 10 and expo 46.0.9.
I was trying to have android emulator for expo app project. I installed Android studio and set the path in environment variables. When i run my app in VS code terminal using

```
npm run start
```

and after metro bundling i pressed "a" for android. My AVD mobile appeared on screen but i got following error on the terminal.

> Error: could not connect to TCP port 5554: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5554: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)

I followed a youtube tutorial video. [Youtube tutorial for emulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGIU5aIRi9M). I searched on google but could not find the solution for android studio for expo.

**Current result**
[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNR08.jpg)

**Expected results**
[expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGhzS.png)

Answer (score 14):

I found this solution in another post, try this (it worked for me):

*I have just met this issue and noticed that it was happening due to the hanging ADB server. Mine has been solved by running the following commands:*

```
adb kill-server
```

```
adb start-server
```

Comment: in my case, just killing the process did the job

Answer (score 1):

Just wipe the device data and remove node_modules package.

Then

```
npm install
```

```
npm start
```

press A and wait it to install app.

(I just try this successfully)

Comment: Yeah. It seems that wipe the data solves the problem. In my case I dropped the virtual device and create another.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling on this same issue for 3 days. I knew that something wrong with my port forwarding on `5554` but couldn't find a way to fix. Until I found this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73136231/4122078

Most of article about running Expo or React Native don't mention about allowing a service in WSL to connect with an emulator on the Windows via emulator port.

Basically you can port-forwarding (which I believe it is) using `socat`. You can install by `sudo apt-get install socat` in WSL.

Then run `socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:5554,reuseaddr,fork TCP:$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | tail -n1 | cut -d " " -f 2):5554`.

You need to change `5554` to be your emulator's port if it's running on another port. Checking an emulator's port by running `adb devices`.

Hope it helps someone who struggling this issue in the future.

Comment: This fixed it for me on a Chromebook.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, just killing the `adb` process did the job

Answer (score 0):

Just code in the terminal

```
npm i
```

and wait for it to install all he required dependencies
then restart the project using

`yarn start`
or
`expo start`